# Why is the value in this map NULL?

Tags: flutter, dart

Error: "NoSuchMethodError: 'length' method not found. Receiver: null" when updating map values

```
List<ImageDetails> _images = [
  ImageDetails(
    imagePath: 'assets/images/meal1.jpg',
    date: '2021-11-30',
    details:
        '',
  ),
  ImageDetails(
    imagePath: 'assets/images/meal2.jpg',
    date: '2021-11-30',
    details:
        '',
  ),
];
```

```
    var dateToImages = new Map();
    _images.sort((a,b) => a.date.compareTo(b.date));
    //group images by date
    for (int i = 0; i < _images.length; i++) {
      var d = _images[i].date; //convert string to Datetime
      print("printing datetime in for loop");
      print(d);
      if (dateToImages.containsKey(d)) {
        print("second element");
        var list = dateToImages[d].add(_images[i]);
        dateToImages[d] = list;
      } else {
        print("first element");
        dateToImages[d] = [_images[i]];
      }
    }
    var sortedKeys = dateToImages.keys.toList()..sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
    List<Widget> children = [];
    print("=====printing datetoImages");
    print(dateToImages);
    print("======== printing sortedKeys");
    print(sortedKeys);
    int len = dateToImages['2021-11-30'].length;
```

Below is result of running above code

```
printing datetime in for loop
2021-11-30
first element
printing datetime in for loop
2021-11-30
second element
=====printing datetoImages
{2021-11-30: null}
======== printing sortedKeys
[2021-11-30]
```

After printing some variables, it seems like the issue is with the value for key "2021-11-30" in dateToImages being null... I don't understand why I keep getting null since it seems like the map building process in the for loop seems to be going well? Can anyone shed some light on this bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests you are accessing `length` method which is not available.
since `null` doesn't have `length` method but `list` have it.

So, you may have a logical error, where you think you are returning `list` but the code is returning `null`

In your case:

Your Code is fine except for this part:

```
if (dateToImages.containsKey(d)) {
        print("second element");
        var list = dateToImages[d].add(_images[i]);
        dateToImages[d] = list;
}
```

`add()` method returns `void` which will return `null` to `var list` and `null` will be sent to the map

Update it directly, replace above code with this:

```
if (dateToImages.containsKey(d)) {
        print("second element");
        dateToImages[d].add(_images[i]);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
List<ImageDetails> _images = [
 ImageDetails(
  imagePath: 'assets/images/meal1.jpg',
  date: '2021-12-30',
  details:
      '',
 ),
 ImageDetails(
  imagePath: 'assets/images/meal2.jpg',
  date: '2021-11-30',
  details:
     '',
 ),
]; 

var dateToImages = new Map();

_images.forEach((img){

 if(dateToImages.containsKey(img.date)){
  dateToImages[img.date].add(img);
 }else{
  dateToImages[img.date] = [img];
 }
});

var sortedKeys = dateToImages.keys.toList()..sort((a, b) => 
a.compareTo(b));
print("=====printing datetoImages");
print(dateToImages);
print("======== printing sortedKeys");
print(sortedKeys);

int len = dateToImages['2021-11-30'].length;
```

Output:

```
=====printing datetoImages
{2021-12-30: [Instance of 'ImageDetails'], 2021-11-30: [Instance of 
'ImageDetails']}
======== printing sortedKeys
[2021-11-30, 2021-12-30]
```